# Audio is continue playing after second video is playing in ExoPlayer at android

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am trying do play local video with use ExoPlayer in android, but When I try two video as a one after the other, the audio of the first video continues to play and second video is not play, how can I solve this problem

```java
SimpleExoPlayer exo;
 
public playVideo(Url url,String type){

    if (type.equals("VideoStart")) {
        Timber.i("VideoStart");

        File file = new File(url);
        Uri localUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

        exo = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(context).build();
        exo.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        playerView.setPlayer(exo);

        MediaSource mediaSource = buildMediaSource(localUri, context);
        exo.prepare(mediaSource, true, false);

    } else if (type.equals("VideoEnd")) {

        Timber.i("VideoEnd");
        if (exo != null) {
            Timber.i("ExoStopped");
            exo.setPlayWhenReady(false);
            exo.stop();
            exo.seekTo(0L);
            exo.release();
            exo = null;
        }
    }  
  }

private static MediaSource buildMediaSource(Uri uri, Context context) {
 return new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, Util.getUserAgent(context, "ExoPlayerDemo"))).createMediaSource(uri);

}
```

Calling methods

```java
playVideo(/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.exoplayer/files/Files/test.mp4,"VideoStart");
    
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        playVideo(/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.exoplayer/files/Files/test.mp4,"VideoEnd");
        playVideo(/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.exoplayer/files/Files/second.mp4,"VideoStart");
    }
}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you're not using the same `SimpleExoPlayer` and you're re-creating a new one everytime.

If you want to play multiple video one after another you need to use the [playlist API](https://exoplayer.dev/playlists.html)